# rental agreement for UK standard visitor visa

Tags: visas, uk

I am an Indian citizen applying for UK standard visitor visa.

I am staying in a rented house in my country. I was informed to submit a rental agreement between me and my owner in my country, i.e., India.

I had rental agreement dated 20th August 2017 for 11 months. We did not renew it. I am still staying in same place. Is it sufficient to get a letter from the owner saying I am staying in the same house from 2 years or should I renew the agreement?

Comment: I think a lot depends on what is _usual_ in the housing market in your location. In some places it might be normal to sign a time-limited agreement at first and normal for it to carry over into permanent renting without further paperwork. If that is that case you should reasonably only need to show the agreement and evidence that you're still living there and paying rent. But if it is an _unusual_ situation in your location you would be better advised to get it cleared up first.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It is usual in my country (I am one example :D) where we do make rental agreement in the beginning and not renew... what do you think would be a reasonable evidence to show that I am still living in that house?

Comment: That depends _entirely_ on local customs that I don't know. In some countries something like utility bills or tax papers are a common way to prove where you live. Certainly rent receipts if you get any that are specific enough. If you have bank statements that show your current address _and_ show rent being paid regularly that might also work. How would you prove your address if you were to change banks, take out a loan, or the like?

Comment: @HenningMakholm We pay rent by interment banking.. So, we do have a proof that every month we transfer rent... I do not know what do they do here to change banks or take loan... I did not do any of that..

Comment: If you pay by internet banking this will show up on your bank account statement. Rent receipts would be useful and you should be able to obtain that from your landlord easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to stay in that home longer, better extend the contract or sign a new contract for an other house before your interview.
The people interviewing you are not interested in whether you lived there in the past, they want to know that you return to it after your intended stay in the UK.
A new or renewed contract will do that.